# VueJS2 - Fetch Data from Child Component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

May I know how to fetch all the data to parent file which being input in the children component?

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kqf31-olh-HsUAMjviS

#### index.html

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="form-group" v-for="n in 4">
        <food :lists="foodLists"></food>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('food', require('./Food.vue'));

new Vue({   
    el: '#app',   
    data() {
        return {
            foodList: []
        }   
    },   
    methods: {
        onSubmit: function() {
            console.log(this.foodList);
        }   
    } 
});
```

#### Food.vue

```
<template>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="food" placeholder="Food Name" v-model="lists">
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: [
       'lists'
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't know why you keep `foodLists` as props in every `Food` component ?

Comment: @choasia it's because i want to pass my `data { foodList: [] }` to the child and use it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just thought you iterate foodList in `v-for`.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kqg542NUQ8mPPsrBb_T

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, as stated here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events
you can either use custom events or implement a Centralized State Management with vuex (https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue from the link below which provided by @BogdanL in VueJS Discussion Group.

[https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqgYOV4GjZomsdAM0nI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497987/vuejs2-fetch-data-from-child-component/45504192#45504192)